# Php foreach restriction before the loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I got an array of news items parameters that I loop trough and get the results out

is there any way I loop the array for specific items before I do the foreach ,

I want to loop only trough post with specific category which is fetched before the foreach

```
$get_cats  = $k2tools_params->get('cloud_category');
```

returns an array of allowed categories

than I have

```
       <?php foreach($this->items as $key=> $item): >
          <?php if (in_array($item->category->id,$get_cats)){ ?> 
              // do something 
          <?php} ?>

        <?php endforeach ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
```

this works fine but the issue I have is the pagination wich counts 18 items from `$this->items`

and I have 3 pages of results , but in foreach with my category restriction I have only 2 items , and this is causing  additional 2 empty pages.

so I must restrict the categories befre the foreach , or loop trough `$this->items` first

thnx for any help , I hope you understand .

**dont mind the php tags separating html from php this is joomla templating**

what I kinda want to do is foreach where category id is in array ,

Comment: Why do you have so many opening/closing tags?

Comment: You can write your whole code between two tags like this: `<?php // one line 
// another line
// a third line ...

Comment: it is template output, separating html from php

Answer (score 2):

In order to that properly with pagination, you will have to find some way to modify the original SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(array_keys($items, $get_cats)) {
    // do_something
}
```

or try to use [`array_search`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: cant do it that way ,  im fetching an array of categories above the loop , which comes back ass eg:[0]=>1[1]=>2